# PHP IF and ELSE Statement - conversion from ASP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have had a look around and can't seem to find what I am looking for. I am finally moving over from Classic ASP to PHP. There are a few areas that I need to get a firm grip of, but I do have a really simple one to ask. How can I write the statement below without having to use ELSE inside of PHP...you'll see what I mean when I write it in ASP:

```
<%If Session("userStatus") <> "" Then%>
   View your account
<%Else%>
   Login
<%End If%>
```

You can see from the above that the ASP and HTML are separated which makes it really simple to navigate through the code. However in PHP I can't seem to be able to write it in a similar way without it throwing an error. I can code this by echo (which means I never really break out of the PHP code block) but what if I wanted something similar to:

```
<%If Session("userStatus") <> "" Then%>
   Hi <%=Session(firstname")%>
<%Else%>
   Login
<%End If%>
```

I know this is a really simple noob question, but converting from one language you have been working with for over 15 years is a little tough ;-)

Could someone advise?

Comment: PHP has [an alternative flow control syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for that purpose.

Comment: See also the echo shortcut `<?=$var?>` [documented in the `echo` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (PHP 5.4+ without short_open_tag enabled, otherwise short_open_tag is needed in php.ini)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['userStatus'] != '') { ?>
    Hi <?=$_SESSION['firstname']?>
<?php } else { ?>
    Login
<?php } ?>
```

Will work, there is an alternate syntax; check Michael Berkowski's comment.
Example of which is below:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['userStatus'] != ''): ?>
    Hi <?=$_SESSION['firstname']?>
<?php else: ?>
    Login
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks to all that commented here - they are perfect thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: @NickGreen Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if($_SESSION['username'] != "") : ?>
    View your account
<?php else : ?>
    Login
<?php endif; ?>
```

OR

```
<?php if($_SESSION['username'] != "") { ?>
    View your account
<?php } else { ?>
    Login
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think will be right use "!==" instead of "!="

```
<?php if($_SESSION['username'] !== "") { ?>
    View your account
<?php } else { ?>
    Login
<?php } ?>
```